# undefined offset issue in if condition in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$get_user="SELECT privillage FROM admin_user WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
 // echo $get_user;
 $exe_query=mysql_query($get_user);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($exe_query);
 $privillage_data = unserialize($row['privillage']); 
                  //print_r($privillage_data);
                  //$privillage_data1=explode(",",$privillage_data);
 echo '<pre>';
print_r($privillage_data);
$count=count($privillage_data);
 //echo "Count".$count;

 if($privillage_data[0] == '1' || $privillage_data[1] == '1' || $privillage_data[2] == '1' && $count >=1)
    {
        $priv_add ="true";
        echo "add--".$priv_add."</br>";
    }
else{$priv_add ="false";}

if($count >=2 && $privillage_data[1] == '2' || $privillage_data[0] == '2' || $privillage_data[2] == '2')
    {
        $priv_edit ="true";
        echo "edit--".$priv_edit."</br>";
    }
    else{$priv_edit ="false";}

    if($count ==3 && $privillage_data[2] == '3' || $privillage_data[0] == '3' || $privillage_data[1] == '3')
     {
        $priv_delete ="true";
        echo "delete--".$priv_delete."</br>";
    }
    else{$priv_delete ="false";}
```

?>

i'm getting undefined offset error in **if** condition,when using the above code!!
how to solve the offset issue!!
Need in help!!kindly make me simple

Comment: Then use `isset` to check it

Comment: where is the definition of your `$privillage_data` and `$count` ?

Comment: i tried isset()....i undefined issue went,but my expected result will not come

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have empty values for array index

try with `isset()` or `empty()` like

`isset($privillage_data[0])`  or `!empty($privillage_data[0])`

and so on... for all index

so your condition will be

```
if((!empty($privillage_data[0]) && $privillage_data[0] == '1') || (!empty($privillage_data[1]) && $privillage_data[1] == '1') || (!empty($privillage_data[2]) && $privillage_data[2] == '1') && $count >=1)
```

and so on for all conditions you are using

Comment: if i add isset() means, i can overcome the error,but my privileges are not set for the corresponding user.

Comment: then you need to proper check your array values

Comment: @kiruthiga, what happens to $priv_add after it is set to true?  Do you do something with that variable after all of the if statements?

Answer (score 1):

Dump out the contents of privillage_data.  There's an array key missing that you're expecting.  Also, which line above is giving the error?

Comment: what do you mean by array key?

Comment: For example, $privillage_data[1].  That is expecting an array such as this array( 'a', 'b' ) with 'a' being at position 0 and 'b' being at position 1.

Comment: even though, i tried with  "$privillage_data ==1" without or condition,the already set privileges are not working correctly

Comment: What does the "print_r($privillage_data);" display?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Comment: Ah ok then on this line:  "if($privillage_data[0] == '1' || $privillage_data[1] == '1' ||"  if that is set to something other than 1, it will fail because when it tries to access privillage_data[1], that does not exist in the array.

Comment: Oh ok.  Is it working as expected now?  If not where is it having a problem?